# Hide Code with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, categories

I want to display the categories as a navigation menu on computers/large displays, but if someone browse the site from a mobile site to hide it.

Can you please look at my code and tell me what I missed?

From the style file:

style.css

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 999px) {

.categories {
     background-color: #1e73be;
     color: #fff;
     width: 220px;
     left: 0px;
     top: 150px;
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     display: table;
     overflow: scroll;
     text-align: center;
 };

...

 @media only screen 
 and (max-device-width: 998px) {
     .categories { display: none; }
      #category { display: none; }
 }
```

categories.php

```php
<?php
  $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
   echo '<h4><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __(        "Νέα για: %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '><div id="category">' . $category->name.'</div></a></h4>';
} 
?>
```

single.php

```php
<nav class="categories">
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/category.php'); ?>
</nav>
```

Thank you for your time! Any other changes to my code are welcome.

Comment: you're not hiding PHP code, in any case you want to hide rendered HTML

Comment: PHP code cannot be hidden because it is never shown to begin with. PHP is a server-side language.

Comment: I agree, you can't hide PHP code. The wording was wrong. I want to say that I call the categories but { display: none; } won't work in order to hide them if the display is small.

Thank you all for your instant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
     `@media (max-width: 998px)`
in place of 
    `@media only screen 
 and (max-device-width: 998px)`

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much Syntax Error!

Comment: @IsidorosRigas -  Anytime bro :)

Answer (score 1):

- this is not a PHP issue. it's HTML and CSS
- you are trying to hide a html element with CSS
- the related CSS attribute is not `min-width`, it's `max-width`

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    #hideme {
        display: none;
    }
}
```